# Parse Server - select a few fields from included object

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, back4app, parse-android-sdk, parse-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to use `.select`(JS) / `selectKeys`(Android) ONLY on the object which is retrieved via `.include()`?

For example, Class A has a pointer to class B.
When I query for Class A, I want all the contents of Class A and only a few selected fields of Class B. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. That's possible. You can do something like this:

```js
const aQuery = new Parse.Query('A');
aQuery.include('pointerToB');
aQuery.select('pointerToB.someFieldOfB');
```

Comment: Yes that work's, I also realized I will have to select all the other fields of "A" that I want or else they get omitted. Thank you .